# React Native App crashing (built apk installed on physical device)

Tags: react-native, expo, adb, eas

I'm experiencing an issue with my react native app built using expo-cli. After generating the apk by:

```
npx eas build -p android --profile preview
```

The apk builds successfully with no errors in expo doctor. However, when installed in physical device it crashes immediately after opening.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "dormdeals",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^7.2.5",
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "^6.2.6",
    "@firebase/app-compat": "^0.2.14",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.3.18",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.14",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "expo": "^49.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "firebase": "^10.0.0",
    "galio-framework": "^0.8.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.6",
    "native-base": "^3.4.28",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.72.1",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-dynamic-vector-icons": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-pie-chart": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.22.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.9.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

eas.json:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.15.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

I ran adb logcat which initially showed missing packages such as RNScreens, RN safe-area-context and RNGestureHandler. I installed all of them and there was no errors shown by the logcat. However, the app still crashes.